# Problems with Nexus devices, ADB and OS X

Tags: android, macos, adb

I got my new Macbook a few days ago and I've been struggling with this problems since then. I cannot connect to my Nexus 5 and Nexus 10 to deploy my apps.

If I type adb devices into command line I can see the device serial number but it says it's offline. I didn't get any dialog on Android devices to confirm debugging authorisation and USB debugging is enabled.

I tried to reboot Macbook and Nexus devices, tried running "android update adb", "adb kill-server" I also tried with different USB cables and tried both USB ports. I played with adb_usb.ini and tried both, PTP and MTP mode.

LG Optimus 4X HD works for some reason without a problem.

Both devices are update to KitKat and Macbook to OS X Mavericks.

Did anyone else had to deal with the same or similar problem? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What does it do when you type `adb shell` ?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix it says `error: device offline`

Comment: You can try to create a VM with linux and try to connect from there to see if it's a problem of OSX

Comment: Can you use Nexus device as an external storage? If you can not do it, may be problem is that a usb-cable too long. If adb can not see device, you should edit file /Users/<name>/.android/adb_usb.ini But your adb see it...

Comment: @DenisMath I can browse the device with Android File Transfer without a problem.

Comment: Ok. Try please add Vendor ID from Application/Utilities/System Information.app to adb_usb.ini file. Add please only one string, it looks like 0x...

Comment: And of course restart adb!

Comment: @DenisMath yeah I tried that too. I have 0x18d1 string in the file, I restarted adb but no success. :(

Comment: (1) Do you have USB debugging enabled on the devices? I'm asking, because you didn't say that you did, and nobody else asked. Ok, if you've done that, (2) make sure the device is *on* and *screen unlocked* when you plug in the USB cable. The debugging authorization screen only comes up when the screen is unlocked for obvious reasons.

Comment: @323go Yeah, USB debugging is enabled but I don't get debugging authorization screen that seems to be the main problem.

Comment: Have you updated your sdk and platform-tools to the latest?

Comment: @323go Yes I have. My ADB version is 1.0.29.

Comment: Mine's 1.0.31. What's the platform tools version in SDK manager? (19.0.2 here).

Comment: @323go Mine is 19.0.2 too. Strange.

Comment: Uninstall (uncheck) and re-install platform tools... or search your drive to see if you have multiple copies of the SDK.

Comment: @323go I uninstalled platform-tools, uninstalled whole Android Studio and deleted SDK from disk. Reinstalled everything. Still ADB 1.0.29 :(

Comment: @323go There was an old version in /usr/bin. Now it's working! Thank you for help.